# Activityindicator stops spinning in Xamarin.forms

Tags: c#, android, xamarin.forms

I want to use activityindicator in xamarin.forms,Activityindicator shows successfully in the middle of the screen,but the spinning animation stops(stuck), have gone through some of the articles ,but it didnot helped.I Have not tested in other devices,but it doesnot work in Android.Here Are the codes-

```
private async Task<string> getUrlString(string id)
    {
        string url = doSomeWork(id);\\its a long running process where it \\takes around 10 minutes to run,And I cant do it in background for some reasons
        return url;
    }
    async void Handle_ItemSelected(object sender, Xamarin.Forms.SelectedItemChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        await DisplayAlert("", "something", "OK");
        activityindicator.IsRunning = true;
        await Task.Delay(250);      int id=1;   
        var url =await getUrlString(id);
        await Navigation.PushModalAsync(new playerPage());
        activityindicator.IsRunning = false;
    }
```

Comment: if your task runs in the MainThread "for some reason" that can explain why the spinners stops...

Comment: Thanks for replying,Yes its runs on main thread,I know the reason why spinning stops,just searching for a proper solution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You try to achive something that is not built for that. When you block the main thread with a long running task, you are not able to tell the main thread he should spinn your activity indicator... why should he do that? He is busy with the long running task.

You have two options:

1) Do not execute long running tasks on the main thread (that's the recommended way)

2) Do not show an animation (like your activity indicator), just show the user a static message "this may take a while... be patient".

But I highly do not recommend you the option 2. Why? The Android system detects, that your app is not responding, when you block the main thread for a long time and may display a message to the user like "app not responding. Do you want to wait or cancel?". Especially then, when the main thread is blocked and the user taps a couple of times on it...

Comment: Yes ,I agree with you and I will accept answer,but before that I want to ask a question-Suppose I have a long running task which I have to run in main thread(due to some reason I dont want in background),an in this case I want to show animation(any animation),because showing a static message... ,may be user will think application got hung.So how I can show any type of animation so that user will think application is active..

Comment: You can't. This is not possible, because you block the main thread. One possible way is, that you (when this is possible in your case) split your task in smaller pieces and every time one part is finished, you update your ui, that the user knows, that something happens and the app is not blocked

Comment: I know you said, "due to some reason I dont want in background"... but why? Can you explain this? Maybe when I understand the reason for this, we can find another way

Comment: Actually my application converts a video to mp3,when user clicks one of the videos in listview,it converts video to mp3 and then the page navigates to another page using pushmodal.Conversion of video to mp3 takes too much time,thats why spinning stops.If I run this background ,I have to show some other stuffs to user.

Comment: Ok. But why not show the user the activity indicator until the mp3 is ready? You just have to wait. So the user knows that something happens. I can't see a major advantage when you do this on the main thread